# Blinking fishing lure, best way to save this design?

Tags: attiny, batteries

**Background**

I ordered 10 PCBs with a design for a blinking fishing lure (it's a hobby project.) I have discovered I made a mistake when I designed it and wanted to see if anyone has any ideas how to best save the situation.

These boards are intended for testing use for a few months to check what colors/flash intervals works etc. In the future the idea is to replace the battery with an energy harvester.

[image]

**Main function**

The board is about 15x10 mm. Battery is 3V lithium, 70 mAh, mounted on the backside. The PCB is molded into the fishing lure with only a small piece exposed to the water. When the water comes in contact with two pads (named Touch in the schematic,) the gate of a MOSFET is pulled high and the main circuit is powered. This is an ATtiny10 that blinks four LEDs for 2 ms, then sleeps for 2 seconds, repeating.

**The problem**

[image: Board]

Everything works as expected, **except** that the GPIOs of the Attiny10 are high when its ground is floating. This means the gate of Q2 is always high and the LEDs are always on except when in contact with water, then they're blinking.

Looking back this wasn't the best way to solve it but sometimes you make mistakes.

**The question**

I would like to salvage this design and im not sure of the best way. I see three ways.

1. **Ideal way would be to find a way which stops the GPIOs from going high when the MCU ground is floating. Possible?**
2. Remove Q3 and solder the drain and source pins together. MCU is now always powered. Put device in power down between blinks and have it always on. Battery would last about 120 days. (A year would have been enough).
3. Remove Q3 and solder the drain and source pins together. Solder a wire between J2 and PB1. PB1 is now pulled low by R1 but will go high in contact with water. This triggers interupt which pulls up MCU from deep sleep. The battery life in this solution would last for many years but adding wires to the board isn't very nice.
4. Other solution you guys may have.

Comment: You could try connecting Q2's source to Q3's drain. That way the LED's can only have ground when Q3 is on aswell. Depending on how Q2's source is connected on the PCB you could do this by breaking the existing trace with a knife, or carefully lift the pin from the pad, and attach some jumper wire.

Comment: @Unimportant That is a very good idea. Its connected to the ground plane but I'll just lift the pin like you said. Thanks!

Comment: @Johan before reading the comments I've thought of same solution as Unimportant proposed. I think it's the best way around and even acceptable permanent solution. If you are "cutting off" ground power just make sure to cut it in every path and you'll be fine.